# Extract word from Url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search function, and would like to display the search term in the search input.

My url is: `search-1.html?keyword=XXXXXX`

How do I get this, and display it in an input?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just one `key=value` in the url you can use simple regex like this:

```
var theValueYouWant = window.location.href.match(/keyword=(.+)/)[1]
```

And set the value of an input like this

```
$('input').val(theValueYouWant)
```

If you want to parse the GET string more thoroughly, this function should do it...

```
gets = {};
$.each(location.search.replace(/^\?/,'').split('&'),function(k,v){
    bits = v.split('=');
    gets[bits[0]] = bits[1];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:
http://ajaxcssblog.com/jquery/url-read-get-variables/

Take luck!

Oh and then you can use the following to display its value in an input field:

```
$("#inputId").val($.url.param("keyword"));
```

Comment: Yeah, I love it. I load it to most of my websites as a habit because of how useful it has been to have (quick and easy) access to GET vars in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Regex solution:

```
var S = window.location.search; // "?keyword=..." etc.
var T = S.match(/^\?(?:[^\b]*&+)?keyword=([^&]*)/);
if (T)
   T = T[1]
else
   T = "no keywords found"
```

If multiple values are given for "keyword" (e.x. `?keyword=XXX&keyword=YYY`), the regex will only find the first of these values (e.x. `XXX`). This regex works even if there are other variables in the query string.

Comment: @pinkie, this happens because the script in jsfiddle runs in an `iframe`. If you use the `iframe` url of http://fiddle.jshell.net/pLHGh/show/light/?hi=1&hi2=2 it works.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-less solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $_GET=[],pairs=location.href.toString().substring(location.href.toString().indexOf("?")+1).split("&");for(key in pairs){pos=pairs[key].indexOf("=");$_GET[pairs[key].substring(0,pos)]=decodeURIComponent(pairs[key].substring(pos+1).replace(/\+/g," "))};

// Now just access with $_GET
// example...
keyword = $_GET["keyword"];
</script>
```